# Issue with MongoDB Authentication and Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, apache-camel

I have a issue with MongoDb Connection.I'm using a Camel with mongo,and I try connect without authentication then the connection it's ok. But, when I try connect Mongo with authentication not works.

My Processor is (it's OK) :

```
 from("timer:aTimer?fixedRate=true&period=10s")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
                .to("jetty:http://localhost:3030/getFile")
                .marshal(xmlJsonFormat)
                .process("camelProcessor")
                .to("mongodb:mongoBean?database=eicas&collection=sales&operation=insert")
                .to("log:Ok:Se guardo un registro Venta fija");
```

and my application-configuration without mongo auth:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
        <camel:routeBuilder ref="vinodroute"/>
    </camel:camelContext>

    <bean id="mongoBean" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
        <constructor-arg name="host" value="localhost" />
        <constructor-arg name="port" value="27017" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jetty" class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty8.JettyHttpComponent8"/>
    <bean id="vinodroute" class="camel.venta.CamelMongoRoute"/>
    <bean id="camelProcessor" class="camel.venta.CamelProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

The question is, How I connect mongo with autenthication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MongoClientURI` object to create the `MongoClient` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
        <camel:routeBuilder ref="vinodroute"/>
    </camel:camelContext>

    <bean id="mongoBean" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="mongoClientURI" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoClientURI" class="com.mongodb.MongoClientURI">
        <constructor-arg name="uri" value="mongodb://username:password@localhost/eicas" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jetty" class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty8.JettyHttpComponent8"/>
    <bean id="vinodroute" class="camel.venta.CamelMongoRoute"/>
    <bean id="camelProcessor" class="camel.venta.CamelProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's Work!!!! I'm happy!!! 

I have another question. If the same conffiguration, I want change the port of Mongo, How I do it?

Comment: mongodb://username:password@localhost:12345/eicas

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer